# How to delete all old indices without elasticsearch-curator?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to delete the old(let say last 10 days) indices from elasticsearch without using curator. Is there any other way to delete all old indices?. (Is there a way to delete indices using Node.js)

Note: I have googled about it but did not find any proper answers and also many are using curator.

Comment: What the naming pattern of your indices?

Comment: @Val my indices pattern is "tenentidentifier_appidentifier_instanceidentifier_@timestamp"

Comment: You can create your own script (even in Bash) to delete your old indicies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the delete index API directly? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html

In order to find which index is the oldest, in case there is no naming convention around the indices names or rollover, you can just check what is the min & max timestamp in each index, and then decide based on that which indices to delete. a simple query to get these timestamp from an index can be found here: [What's the fastest manner to retrieve min timestamp from Elasticsearch indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016019/whats-the-fastest-manner-to-retrieve-min-timestamp-from-elasticsearch-indices/54018386#54018386)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. we have to manually delete the logs if we use "Delete Index API". what curator does is, it will delete all the old logs according to the scheduled time. we can delete the logs automatically by mentioning the time and date. So, it deletes for us. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: ok, I still don't understand why you can't use curator, as it does exactly this. you will need to run the Curator through a cron or any other scheduler, just like you'll run a script that uses the delete API directly, with script scheduled in cron.